# How to change row to column in datatable

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

h:datatable created table like this

```
column 1 column 2
 item 1    item 1
 item 2    item 2
 item 3     ....
```

But it is possible to change something and created this?

```
column1 item 1 item 2 item 3
column2 item 1 item 2 item 3
```

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523669/how-do-i-display-data-in-horizontal-orientation-in-jsf-as-repeater-in-asp-net) what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you mean you want a query that returns things in that order, or you want to redefine your table in this way? Also, why do you want to do this?  Columns and rows in a database have very different purposes.  It seems unlikely that it would be useful to actually switch their uses in all but the rarest of cases.

Comment: As query? Or what do you need?

Comment: @Flimzi and @megaperlz, the question is about JSF. The query is just standard SQL, what he is asking is changing how to represent them with the datatable element of JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `h:datatable` directly to access row oriented data retrieved from a datasource, in this way.

You could create a new collection in your backing bean which holds the data in the format
you need (column1 item 1 item 2 item 3 ).
See also [is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-rows-with-jsf-hdatatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315357/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-rows-with-jsf-hdatatable)