# How to create several rows on JSF Datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable

I need to create a table with this structure:

```
Column A     Column B     Column C     Column D
 xxxx         xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
Column E     Column F     Column G     Column H
 xxxx         xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
```

This is gonna be repeated `N` times, according to the amount of items on my list.

I made a Google search and didn't find any example with multiple rows.

I have tried using `datatable`inside the main `datatable` but no results.

Comment: is it close ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf

Comment: nah...I gave a look at those PrimeFaces examples and nothing is close to what I need but thanks

Comment: take a look at this http://datatables.net/ might find some thinig over there , and you can itegrate it with JSF

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm gonna check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `HTML` table and use EL and  if necessary, that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
   <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td>column A</td>
              <td>column B</td>
              <td>column C</td>
              <td>column D</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>#{item.columnA}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnB}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnC}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnD}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>column E</td>
              <td>column F</td>
              <td>column G</td>
              <td>column H</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>#{item.columnE}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnF}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnG}</td>
              <td>#{item.columnH}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach using standard JSF components would be to just render the cell values below each other in a single column/cell.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <h:column>#{item.columnA}<br/>#{item.columnE}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{item.columnB}<br/>#{item.columnF}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{item.columnC}<br/>#{item.columnG}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{item.columnD}<br/>#{item.columnH}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

You could if necessary wrap each value in a `<div>` and throw in some CSS accordingly with the right dimensions, borders and backgrounds to make it look like a real row.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `List<Object[]>` accord to your needed and get it on value attribute on `<h:datatable>` [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315357/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-rows-with-jsf-hdatatable/42306841#42306841).